# Handles without springs: strong door latches

Tags: doors

Our internal doors use old Edwardian door handles. However, the handles don't have a spring. The latch we have doesn't have enough strength to work the handle (they sag).

I've tried searching for "strong door latches", but this seems to focus on security and buying a more expensive latch at our local shop doesn't solve the issue either.

So what latch should I use when the handles do not have springs?

Comment: I just did a quick search on 'Edwardian door handle' and came up with this site.  http://www.theperiodironmonger.co.uk/  Looks like they have replacement hardware for your doors.

Comment: Thanks. By door latch I mean http://www.theperiodironmonger.co.uk/bathroom-dead-bolt-3inch---heavy-duty~987 But it's not clear if that latch is particularly strong.

Comment: Try giving the site a call, seems they are pretty customer service friendly.  I bet they would have the answers you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key (no pun intended) phrase to search for is "double sprung". I couldn't find these latches at any of my local DIY stores, so I ordered online.